# Aggregate bitfield values with binary OR

Tags: sql-server, aggregate-functions, bit-manipulation, bit-fields

I have a table with *int* values being used as bitfields (where each bit is a flag).

Now I would like to aggregate them with a binary operation (in my case OR) so that:

```
SELECT 1 AS bitfield
INTO #TABLE
UNION ALL SELECT 1 + 2 + 8 + 32
UNION ALL SELECT 2 + 128
UNION ALL SELECT 2 + 32

SELECT AND_AGGR(bitfield) -- Invalid because AND_AGGR doesn't exist
FROM #TABLE

DROP #TABLE
```

would result in the value `171`

What would be a good way to do this that hopefully doesn't require a lot of `|` and `MAX` (but if you must, you must)?

I am using MS SQL Server 2008 myself, but solutions on other servers are also of interest.

Comment: "Now I would like to aggregate them with a binary operation (in my case AND)" Are you sure you mean "AND" and not "OR"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're expecting the result `171`, surely you mean binary `OR` not `AND`?

In any case, this solution aggregates the values into a variable:

```
SELECT 1 AS bitfield
INTO #TABLE
UNION ALL SELECT 1 + 2 + 8 + 32
UNION ALL SELECT 2 + 128
UNION ALL SELECT 2 + 32

DECLARE @i int = 0

SELECT @i = @i | bitfield
FROM #TABLE

SELECT @i

DROP TABLE  #table
```

This might not meet your requirements if you want to group the aggregation by another field.

It is also unlikely to perform well on a large table.

Comment: In my example you can use that solution. In the real case I wish to group by some other fields though, but I assume the `MAX(bitfield | 1) + ...` solution given by Mark Byers will work in that case.

Answer (score 3):

On MySQL and PostgreSQL you can use [`BIT_OR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_bit-or).

I don't think SQL Server has this aggregate function.

You could do it with lots of `MAX` and `&` as you said:

```
MAX(x & 1) + MAX(x & 2) + ... + MAX(x & 128)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Ah, so we simply have the wrong database solution in this single case. But thanks for the answer as it helped prove my suspicions.

Answer (score 0):

In MS SQL Server

```
DECLARE @agg  VARCHAR(MAX) = '0001,0011,0101,0101,0101'
SELECT CONVERT(binary(4), VALUE, 2) , VALUE  FROM STRING_SPLIT( @agg , ',')

DECLARE @sum AS BIGINT = 0
DECLARE @mul AS BIGINT = 0xffffffff
SELECT  @sum |= v
   , @mul &= v
FROM STRING_SPLIT( @agg , ',')
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (CONVERT(binary(4), VALUE, 2))) _(v)

PRINT FORMAT(@sum,'X8')
PRINT FORMAT(@mul,'X8')
```

Prints

```
            VALUE
---------- ------------
0x00010000 0001
0x00110000 0011
0x01010000 0101
0x01010000 0101
0x01010000 0101

01110000
00010000
```

In more complex word you need:

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.BOR( @agg VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS BIGINT
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @sum AS BIGINT = 0
SELECT  @sum |= CONVERT(BIGINT, VALUE)
FROM STRING_SPLIT( @agg , ',')
RETURN @sum
END

GO
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.BAND( @agg VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS BIGINT
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @mul AS BIGINT = 0xffffffffffffffff
SELECT  @mul &= CONVERT(BIGINT, VALUE)
FROM STRING_SPLIT( @agg , ',')
RETURN @mul
END
GO
```

when using bitmap of payment periods

```
;WITH delayedPayment AS
(SELECT * FROM ( VALUES 
    ( 123, 67, '2020-2-1')
   ,( 123, 67, '2020-4-1')
   ,( 123, 67, '2020-5-1')
   ,( 123, 67, '2020-6-1')
   ,( 123, 68, '2020-6-1')  -- another agreement
   ,( 123, 67, '2020-12-1')
           
   ,( 456, 69, '2020-4-1')
   ,( 456, 69, '2020-8-1')
   ,( 456, 69, '2020-10-1')
   ,( 456, 69, '2020-11-1')) _(cuno, loan, missedDuedate)
)
, delayPattern AS
(SELECT cuno
   ,  sum_months
   ,  bor_months
   ,  IIF( FORMAT( CAST(bor_months AS BIGINT), 'X16') LIKE '%111%', 'dalyad 3+ month in row', NULL) delayState
   FROM (SELECT cuno
         , SUM(POWER( 16.0, CONVERT( BIGINT, DATEDIFF( month, missedDuedate, '2020-12-1')))) sum_months
         , dbo.BOR( STRING_AGG( CONVERT( BIGINT, POWER( 16.0, DATEDIFF( month, missedDuedate, '2020-12-1'))),',')) bor_months
      FROM delayedPayment
      GROUP BY cuno
   ) s
)
SELECT cuno
   ,  FORMAT( CAST(sum_months AS BIGINT), 'X16') sum_months
   ,  FORMAT( CAST(bor_months AS BIGINT), 'X16') bor_months
   ,  delayState
FROM delayPattern

cuno    sum_months          bor_months          delayState
123     00000*10112*000001  00000*10111*000001  dalyad 3+ month in row
456     0000000100010110    0000000100010110    NULL
```

But sometimes just one need to think and you can do it with SUM

```
, delayPattern AS -- optimal
(SELECT cuno
   ,  bor_months
   ,  IIF( FORMAT( CAST(bor_months AS BIGINT), 'X16') LIKE '%111%', 'dalyad 3+ month in row', NULL) delayState
   FROM (SELECT cuno
         , SUM(POWER( 16.0, missedmonth)) bor_months
      FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT cuno
               , missedmonth
            FROM delayedPayment
            CROSS APPLY (VALUES ( DATEDIFF( month, missedDuedate, '2020-12-1'))) _(missedmonth)
            GROUP BY cuno, missedmonth
            ) ss
      GROUP BY cuno
   ) s
)

SELECT cuno
   ,  FORMAT( CAST(bor_months AS BIGINT), 'X16') bor_months
   ,  delayState
FROM delayPattern
```

Will print

```
cuno    bor_months  delayState
123 0000010111000001    dalyad 3+ month in row
456 0000000100010110    NULL
```

NOTE: I am using HEX format and POWER(16.0, X) , just to be lazy, POWER(2.0, X) will be correct, but then you need bin->string formatter. Something like this:

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.toBinaryString(@p INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(24)
AS 
BEGIN 
RETURN  REVERSE(REPLACE( REPLACE( 
    REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( 
    REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( 
    REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( 
    REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( FORMAT(@p,'X8'), 
        '0', '....'), '1', '...x'),'2', '..x.'),'3', '..xx'),
        '4', '.x..'), '5', '.x.x'),'6', '.xx.'),'7', '.xxx'),
        '8', 'x...'), '9', 'x..x'),'A', 'x.x.'),'B', 'x.xx'),
        'C', 'xx..'), 'D', 'xx.x'),'E', 'xxx.'),'F', 'xxxx'),
        '.','0'),'x','1'))
END
```